# React-Native focus Button on render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, accessibility

I try to test my React-Native on Android TV. On first screen, i've an ButtonList component.

By default, i would like "focus" first button, and with remote control switch on the right/left.

You can see an example :

[image]

The first "right" control not trigger (visualy) "M3U file" Button, and "Account" Button does not seem focus (not opacity style).

My code :

```
<View style={styles.tabs} accessible>
  <Button
    mode={buttonMode(isAccountLoginType)}
    style={styles.buttonNav}
    onPress={() => setLoginType(ACCOUNT)}>
    Account
  </Button>
  <Button
    mode={buttonMode(isM3uFileLoginType)}
    style={styles.buttonNav}
    onPress={() => setLoginType(M3U_FILE)}>
    M3U file
  </Button>
  <Button
    mode={buttonMode(isPlaylistIdLoginType)}
    style={styles.buttonNav}
    onPress={() => setLoginType(PLAYLIST_ID)}>
    Playlist ID
  </Button>
</View>
```

Anyone have already play with React-Native with focus element ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you give me a snack url?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this may be that can help. Instead of using multiple button you can use List that contain the tabs name and return through a map
[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-clarke-wom41?file=/src/App.js)